# Using reversion with GeoDjango in Django admin

Tags: python, django-admin, geodjango, django-reversion

I know how to use django-reversion and geodjango for admin site separately. 
my class looks like this:

```
class My_model_Admin(admin.GeoModelAdmin, reversion.VersionAdmin):

    list_display = ('id', 'name')

admin.site.register(My_model, My_model_Admin, admin.GeoModelAdmin)
```

I get an error because admin.register expects "2 to 3 arguments and 4 given".

What is the alternative ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! The right syntax is:

```
class My_model_Admin(reversion.VersionAdmin ,admin.GeoModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('id', 'name')

admin.site.register(My_model, My_model_Admin)
```

Apparently the order matters. And there is no need to declare GeoModelAdmin in admin.site.register because it's already been taken care of.

Hope will help someone!